# Get, set and print out an array of chars, from a struct in C using pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct

Could someone explain to me why I cannot print out this variable from a struct? I believe it is something to do with how my pointers are set up but I can't seem to get it.

I've currently got it so that it takes in the user input for a shape type e.g. Circle, Square, Triangle. This input is set into an array of chars called type. There is a struct called Shape which contains type and x and y coordinates. I'm trying to set the user input type into this struct and print out the results for that shape.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Shape {
    char type;
    int x;
    int y;
}Shape;

static int setShape (char type[], int xpos, int ypos)
{
    Shape shape;
    shape.type = *type;
    shape.x = xpos;
    shape.y = ypos;

    printf("=== SHAPE ===\n %s:\n  x:%d\n  y:%d\n", &shape.type, shape.x, shape.y);

    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char type[8];
    int xpos = 100;
    int ypos = 100;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if ( strcmp (argv[i], "Circle") == 0)
    {
        strncpy(type, "Circle", 8);
        }
        else if ( strcmp (argv[i], "Square") == 0)
        {
            strncpy(type, "Square", 8);
        }
        else if ( strcmp (argv[i], "Triangle") == 0)
        {
            strncpy(type, "Triangle", 8);
        }
    }

    rc = setShape(type, xpos, ypos);
    if(rc != 0) {
        printf("Error setting shape.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If it input: 
    ./shape Circle

Output:

```
=== SHAPE ===
CLAd:
  x:100
  y:100
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the statement `shape.type = *type;` you are trying to write first character from array `type` into struct char `type`. If this is what you want, change the print method to:

```
printf("=== SHAPE ===\n %c:\n  x:%d\n  y:%d\n", shape.type, shape.x, shape.y);
```

Else you wanted entire passed array `type` to function `setShape()` and assign it to a string allocate enough sizeof(type) as below in the struct declaration as:

```
typedef struct Shape {
   char type[8];
   int x;
   int y;
}Shape;
```

and initialize the array type as:

```
memcpy(&shape.type , type, sizeof(shape.type));
```

and change the print method to:

```
printf("=== SHAPE ===\n %s:\n  x:%d\n  y:%d\n", shape.type, shape.x, shape.y);
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, thanks for the explanation of my current implementation and what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The struct contains a single character "type" rather than actual storage for an array of them; you're then trying to point it at a local buffer you define in main, which isn't in scope where you try to use it.

Change the struct to;

```
typedef struct Shape {
    char type[8];
    int x;
    int y;
}Shape;
```

and then change your strncpy's accordingly.